# How to make connectivity between sqlite3 file and iphone application?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite

i am working on a application which needs connectivity with database i had create database and import it successfully but i dont know how connect it with code can any help me?

Comment: Take help from these tutorials http://www.iphonesdkarticles.com/category/sqlite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me google it for you.

1. http://dblog.com.au/iphone-development-tutorials/iphone-sdk-tutorial-reading-data-from-a-sqlite-database/
2. http://www.icodeblog.com/2008/08/19/iphone-programming-tutorial-creating-a-todo-list-using-sqlite-part-1/

Answer (score 1):

The sqlite framework is available on the iPhone, you first need to import it (it's called libsqlite3.0.dylib).
Bear in mind that it's all in C so you have to be comfortable with that.
There are already many tutorials on the Internet on how to use it in an iPhone application.

If you'd rather go the Objective-C way, there is an excellent wrapper around the sqlite C API for the iPhone called FMDatabase: https://github.com/lightory/fmdb

Also, you could have a look at Core Data which, again, will do most of the nasty tasks for you.